# a generic extension method for classes with common methods but no inheritance

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working with a COM library in my .Net 3.5 project that has a bunch (about 20-30) of collection type interfaces. Each of these classes exposes things a property called `Count` and methods called `ItemByIndex(int)` and `GetEnumerator()` (which is of type `System.Collections.IEnumerator`).

However, each of these interfaces is implemented them on their own and not in a common parent class.

Is there a way to write a generic extension method that converts the collection object to a List<>? This is what I'm currently doing, but I have 20 or so of these methods copied and pasted.

```
public static List<iml.IManDocument> ToList(this iml.IManDocuments source)
{
    List<iManDocument> results = new List<iManDocument>(source.Count);
    for (int i = 1; i <= source.Count; i++)
    {
        results.Add((iml.IManDocument)source.ItemByIndex(i));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should make your types implement [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, I'm guessing you can't do that...

You can do this with builtin methods (making use of the fact that they are `IEnumerable`):

```
var list = myIManDocuments.Cast<IManDocument>().ToList();
```

You could do it with `dynamic`, but this has downsides, the biggest one being that you don't get any compile-time checking that you're doing this with compatible types.

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(dynamic source)
{
    List<T> results = new List<T>(source.Count);
    for (int i = 1; i <= source.Count; i++)
    {
        results.Add(source.ItemByIndex(i));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Use like:

```
var list = MyUtil.ToList<IManDocument>(myIManDocuments);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can not add extension methods based on existing methods, and neither you can add interfaces dynamically to types that fit those interface (both would be great and useful things).

One option would be to add the extension method for `object` and use reflection to figure out whether the required methods and properties exists.

```
public static List<iml.IManDocument> ToListByReflection(this object source)
{
    var type = source.GetType();
    var countProperty = type.GetProperty("Count");
    var itemByIndexMethod = type.GetMethod("ItemByIndex", new[] { typeof(int) });

    if (countProperty == null || itemByIndexMethod == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Type does not offer required methods.");
    }

    var count = countProperty.GetValue(source);
    var results = new List<iManDocument>(count);
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        results.Add((iml.IManDocument)itemByIndexMethod.Invoke(source, new object[] { i });
    }

    return results;
}
```

For better performance you could even cache the property and method infos for each different type.

But just writing a method like you did is in my opinion really the better option. It's clearer what it does, it's type-safe at compilation time (worth a lot!) and faster than reflection. It's just one time writing per type, and mostly it's copy-paste anyway.

Answer (score 0):

List has a constructor which accepts an IEnumerable as argument. Since IEnumerable has only (the generic) GetEnumerator  you could easily make your interfaces derive from IEnumerable (the generic one) and use the List constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the library classes (using the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern ), and make them implement the IList interface.